# Rails 3.2.21 instrumenter stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app running on 3.2.21 and I keep on getting this error:

```
A SystemStackError occurred in profile#update: 

stack level too deep 
activesupport (3.2.21) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23
```

Its happening on one specific endpoint but when I go and try to reproduce it with the exact same parameters, I can never get it to fail. Its a strange error as that is all of the information that I am given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this. The reason was a circular structure I used in a call like

```
render json: my_circular_structure
```

Perhaps that's also the problem in your case.